# Something is scrolling back to 0,0 after document loaded

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, scroll, turbolinks

I have this JS to scroll to a specific place on pageload (which, for Rails with Turbolinks, is on Turbolinks load):

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  window.scrollTo(240,1);
});
```

But when I load a page, it loads at `240,1` for a split second, and then jerks back to `0,0`.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this delayed scroll to `0,0`?

I have also tried replacing `"turbolinks:load"` with `"page:load"` and `"ready"`, they don't work either.

Things that might be relevant:

- Chrome desktop
- Ruby on Rails 5.2.3
- Turbolinks 5
- No other custom JS

Comment: Write a script to add an event listener to listen scroll on window and do some console.log() on it. Paste it into DEV TOOLS console. Now using this console.log(), add a breakpoint and see the call stack which function is messing with the scrollTop.

Comment: Could you put that as an answer, and maybe explain how to write that listener? I'm not super good at JS

Comment: Were you able to debug the problem?

Comment: @TusharShukla yes, it was Chrome's history remembering scroll positions (even though the position was 0,0). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';`. It should prevent the page from scrolling back to a previous position.

Comment: This was it—I was navigating through history, and Chrome likes to scroll to where the window was (even if it happens to be 0,0)

Answer (score 2):

Add this script to dev tools console

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
  console.log("Window scrolled");
}
```

Now add a breakpoint and check the call stack as shown in the image below.

This will show you all of the functions that are changing the window scroll.
Note that, if you scroll the page yourself, this function would be executed even then as well.

[image]

Hope it helps!!